# Restoring database from .sql file is failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to use C# to restore a blank database's tables from an sql file I have.

This is the code:

```
namespace KezberProjectManager
{
    public partial class VisitClear : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=JOSH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KezBlu;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(
    HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, 
    @"App_Data\kb.sql"));

            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the script:

```
USE [KezBlu]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Customer_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Customer_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Status_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Status_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Group_Employee]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] DROP CONSTRAINT [Group_Employee]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] DROP CONSTRAINT [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_LockedDate]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_LockedDate]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Project]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Project]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Recurring_Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] DROP CONSTRAINT [Recurring_Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Project_Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Project_Task]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Task1]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task1]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Project_Task]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task1]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Task]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Cases]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Customer_Case]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Case]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] DROP CONSTRAINT [Status_Case]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Cases]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Project]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project] DROP CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Project]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Project]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] DROP CONSTRAINT [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[LockedDates]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_LockedDate]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] DROP CONSTRAINT [Employee_Schedule]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] DROP CONSTRAINT [Recurring_Schedule]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employee]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] DROP CONSTRAINT [Group_Employee]
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Colors]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Colors]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customers]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Group]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Recurring]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Recurring]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Settings]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Settings]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Statuses]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Statuses]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Statuses]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Statuses](
    [StatusID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StatusDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Statuses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StatusID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Settings]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Settings](
    [SettingID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SettingKey] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SettingValue] [text] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Settings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SettingID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Recurring]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recurring](
    [RecurringID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Period] [int] NULL,
    [DateStart] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateLast] [datetime] NULL,
    [Advance] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Recurring] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecurringID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [GroupID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GroupDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsReadOnly] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.[Group]]] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GroupID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customers]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerDescription] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Colors]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Colors](
    [ColorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ColorValue] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Colors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ColorID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Employee]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeEmail] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EmployePassword] [char](44) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultNumWeek] [smallint] NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule](
    [ScheduleID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [Hours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [EmployeID] [int] NULL,
    [RecurringID] [int] NULL,
    [Priority] [int] NULL,
    [DateTo] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsLocked] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [BumpPriority] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Schedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ScheduleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[LockedDates]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates](
    [LockedDateID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsYearly] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.LockedDates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LockedDateID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters](
    [EmployeGroupFilterID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.EmployeGroupFilters] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeGroupFilterID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Project]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project](
    [ProjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectTitle] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleID] [int] NULL,
    [EstimatedHours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [IsRetired] [bit] NULL,
    [Color] [int] NULL,
    [PaymoID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Project] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProjectID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Cases]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cases](
    [CaseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CaseTitle] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CaseDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleID] [int] NULL,
    [EstimatedHours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NULL,
    [Color] [int] NULL,
    [CRMID] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Cases] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CaseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task](
    [TaskID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TaskTitle] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [TaskDescription] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [ScheduleID] [int] NULL,
    [PaymoID] [int] NULL,
    [ParentScheduleID] [int] NULL,
    [IsUnscheduelable] [bit] NULL,
    [EstimatedHours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [PaymoUser] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [PaymoOrder] [int] NULL,
    [PaymoEstimateHours] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Task] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TaskID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Customer_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Customer_Case] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Customer_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Case] FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([ScheduleID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Status_Case]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Status_Case] FOREIGN KEY([StatusID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Statuses] ([StatusID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cases] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Status_Case]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Group_Employee]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Group_Employee] FOREIGN KEY([GroupID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Group] ([GroupID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Group_Employee]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Employee_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Group_EmployeGroupFilter] FOREIGN KEY([GroupID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Group] ([GroupID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeGroupFilters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Group_EmployeGroupFilter]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_LockedDate]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Employee_LockedDate] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LockedDates] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Employee_LockedDate]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Project]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Project] FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([ScheduleID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Project]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Employee_Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Employee_Schedule] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Employee_Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Recurring_Schedule]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Recurring_Schedule] FOREIGN KEY([RecurringID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Recurring] ([RecurringID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Recurring_Schedule]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Project_Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Project_Task] FOREIGN KEY([ProjectID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Project] ([ProjectID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Project_Task]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Task]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task] FOREIGN KEY([ScheduleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([ScheduleID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [Schedule_Task1]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 21:35:08 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task1] FOREIGN KEY([ParentScheduleID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Schedule] ([ScheduleID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Schedule_Task1]
GO
```

I have the drops in there because the database might already be setup in which case I want a fresh copy.

I get:

```
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
```

Is there anything wrong with what I am doing? I got the script from generating it with SQL Server.

I just want it to:

```
 1. Clear any tables, just empty the db.

2. Create the tables and foreign keys.
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try to execute it directly in Management Studio? How about if you break it down into chunks and execute in Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because the GO word is not recognized when you pass the full script as a simple string to ExecuteNonQuery. However, the [overload of ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199328.aspx) that takes a StringCollection object is stated that accepts a script separated by the GO

I will try in this way: (Not tested)

```
StringCollection col = new StringCollection();
col.Add(script);
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(col);
```

if this doesn't work then the only workaround that comes to mind is

```
string goSplitter = new string[] { "\r\nGO\r\n" };
string[] cmdParts = script.Split(goSplitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
StringCollection col = new StringCollection();
col.AddRange(cmdParts);
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(col);
```

**UPDATE**
I have tested a small part of your script agains a database of mine with the code you have provided, and contrary to what is my understanding of the documentation about [ExecuteNonQuery with a single string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199350%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), it has worked as expected. So it is possible that you have some syntax error or other problem in the whole script. I suggest to test it inside the Sql Management Studio console

**UPDATE 2**
Now I was really curious, so I fired up Reflector to investigate the code of ExecuteNonQuery and now the mistery is solved. These are the first decompiled lines of the method that gets a single string.

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
{
    int num6;
    this.CheckDisconnected();
    int statementsToReverse = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    StringCollection strings = this.GetStatements(sqlCommand, executionType, ref statementsToReverse);
    ........
```

So the single string is passed to an internal method called GetStatements that return a StringCollection

Answer (score 0):

That script is not pure SQL. GO statement is not part of SQL langauge but part of editor preprocesor to separate SQL batch statments. You can't execute such script with SqlCommand and ExecuteNonQuery method.

What you need is sqlcmd.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack has an article that describes a library he created that allows you to run a SQL comment that contains `GO` statements.

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/11/04/a-library-for-executing-sql-scripts-with-go-separators-and.aspx

You would need to use a library such as this to run the script you have.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already stated that GO is a part of SSMS, however ; is a part of sql, so if you end the last line of each statement with ; instead of go, it should execute from inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has errors in it.
I ran copied and pasted it, ran it twice (to create table structure) and I get error messages such as

Could not drop object 'dbo.Employee' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

You have to drop the tables in the correct order.
Start from the tables that have the references... 
example drop firt [EmployeGroupFilters] then Employee etc.

Good luck.

Comment: Another thing, I would recommend modifying your drop table to check if the table exists first in order to avoid having error reports.
something like :
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Employee]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
  drop table [dbo].[Employee]